# how to set ID for every bubble message and then update using its ID

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

**Easy way to understand what is my question play the following video and see what is my problem.**
https://vimeo.com/315390850

if you dont have a good inernet connection then read the following sentences.

I am going to update bubble messages but i dont know how to update specific message by Id.
Example: in html there is and Id for every tag within a list and if we have to update then we select it by id and then update it.
So how to make a concept like that for react-native-gifted-chat bubble messages?

I tried to use refs with setNativeProps function but did not work.

```
render(){
 return (
   <GiftedChat
         extraData={this.state}
         messages={this.state.messages}
          onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
          user={{
              _id: this.state.userId,
           }}
           renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
           renderInputToolbar={this.renderInputToolbar.bind(this)}
      />
 );
}

renderBubble = props => {
        if (props.currentMessage.audio) {
            return (
                <View style={[{ width: 150, height: 70, backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }, props.position === 'left' ? { left: -41 } : {}]}>
                    <EIcon
                        name="google-play"
                        size={30}
                        color={this.state.playAudio ? "red" : "blue"}
                        style={{
                            left: 90,
                            position: "relative",
                            shadowColor: "#000",
                            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
                            shadowOpacity: 0.5,
                            backgroundColor: "transparent"
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                                playAudio: true
                            });
                            const sound = new Sound(props.currentMessage.audio, "", error => {

                                if (error) {
                                    console.log("failed to load the sound", error);
                                }

                                const duration = sound.getDuration();
                                const progressPhase = 1 / duration;

                                if (duration !== 0) {
                                    this._interval = setInterval(() => {

                                        this.setState({
                                            progress: this.state.progress += progressPhase
                                        });

                                        if (this.state.progress >= 1) {
                                            clearInterval(this._interval);
                                            this.setState({
                                                progress: 0.0,
                                                playAudio: false
                                            });
                                        }

                                    }, 1000);
                                }

                                sound.play(success => {
                                    console.log(success, "success play");
                                    if (!success) {
                                        Alert.alert("There was an error playing this audio");
                                    }
                                });

                            });
                        }}
                    />


                    <Progress.Circle progress={this.state.progress} showsText size={35} />

                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Bubble
                    {...props}
                    textStyle={{
                        right: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                        left: {
                            color: '#fff',
                        },
                    }}
                    wrapperStyle={{
                        left: {
                            backgroundColor: "orange",
                            left: -41
                        },
                        right: {
                            backgroundColor: 'green'
                        }
                    }}
                />
            );
        }
    }
```

*Here I have a chatbox when I send multiple audio message for example 3 aduio message: audio message .1, audio message .2, audio message .3
aduio message .1 has came first time.
aduio message .3 has came last time.*

*every audio message has a play icon and a progressbar.
When I click on play Icon, then I update the progressbar.
here I used interval for one click on play icon, the progressbar gets update multiple time until gets complete.*

**My Problem is: when i click the play icon of audio message .1 just the last audio message .3 gets updated.
I want: if I click on audio message .1 the progressbar of audio message .1 should be update. same for audio message .2 and audio message .3.**

Comment: Hey @Iqbal can you please share your final solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by conditional rendering Also I changed following class and I added
this line: ***`next.audio == current.audio ||`***

```
export default class Message extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const next = nextProps.currentMessage;
    const current = this.props.currentMessage;
    const { nextMessage } = this.props;
    const nextPropsMessage = nextProps.nextMessage;
    return (
      next.send !== current.send ||
      next.received !== current.received ||
      next.pending !== current.pending ||
      next.createdAt !== current.createdAt ||
      next.text !== current.text ||
      next.image !== current.image ||
      next.video !== current.video ||
      next.audio == current.audio ||  // this line added by me
      nextMessage !== nextPropsMessage
    );
  }

 //..............

}
```

**I add this condition and please please let me know about performance. this tree line, I added to my code:**

***`this.myPro = <Progress.Circle progress={this.state.progress} showsText size={35} />; this.setState({currentPlayedMessage: props.currentMessage._id }); { props.currentMessage._id === this.state.currentPlayedMessage ? this.myPro : null }`***

**All code:**

```
if (props.currentMessage.audio) {

            this.myPro = <Progress.Circle progress={this.state.progress} showsText size={35} />; // this line added

            return (
                <View style={[{ width: 150, height: 70, backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }, props.position === 'left' ? { left: -41 } : {}]}>
                    <EIcon
                        name="google-play"
                        size={30}
                        color={this.state.playAudio ? "green" : "blue"}
                        style={{
                            left: 90,
                            position: "relative",
                            shadowColor: "#000",
                            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
                            shadowOpacity: 0.5,
                            backgroundColor: "transparent"
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {

                            this.setState({
                                playAudio: true,
                                currentPlayedMessage: props.currentMessage._id // this line added
                            });

                            const sound = new Sound(props.currentMessage.audio, "", error => {

                                if (error) {
                                   return;
                                }

                                const duration = sound.getDuration();
                                const progressPhase = 1 / duration;

                                if (duration !== 0) {
                                    this._interval = setInterval(() => {

                                        this.setState({
                                            progress: this.state.progress += progressPhase
                                        });

                                        if (this.state.progress >= 1) {
                                            clearInterval(this._interval);
                                            this.setState({
                                                progress: 0.0,
                                                playAudio: false
                                            });
                                        }

                                    }, 1000);
                                }

                                sound.play(success => {
                                    console.log(success, "success play");
                                    if (!success) {
                                        Alert.alert("There was an error playing this audio");
                                    }
                                });

                            });
                        }}
                    />


                    { props.currentMessage._id === this.state.currentPlayedMessage ? this.myPro : null } // this line added

                </View>
            );
        }
```

Comment: Here I am just wory about the performance, please if you know better performance than this solution let me know.

Comment: I added the code but i am facing following issue

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz3ED.png

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same issue but i solved it like this in functional component.
first you add **shouldUpdateMessage** in gifted chat component

```
 <GiftedChat
     messages={messages}
      onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
       renderBubble={renderBubble}
       renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar.bind(this)}
       shouldUpdateMessage={(props, nextProps) => { return props.currentMessage.audio == nextProps.currentMessage.audio ? true : false }}        // Add this in your gifted chat

  />
```

Then i solved it like this in the render method, i've just used my code but you can just follow the same method.

```
if (currentMessage.audio) {
       
        const icon=        <Icon key={currentMessage.key} name={'play-arrow'} size={30} type="material" color={ 'blue'} />
        const icon2=        <Icon key={currentMessage.key} name={'multitrack-audio' } size={30} type="material" color={'red'} />
        
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity key={currentMessage.key} onPress={() => {
                setCurrentPlayedMessage(currentMessage.key)

            }} >
               { props.currentMessage.key === currentPlayedMessage ? icon2: icon }     //This Line is responsible for changing a specific message, you can use your component in ternary operator after condition
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <Bubble

            {...props} />
```